# NurbsCurve MatrixMath Maya api Python

Tags: python, math, matrix, maya, nurbs

I am creating a toolset for creating nurbs curves/surfaces inside maya using python.

I have a set of dictionaries that include cvPositions, knots, form etc. each of which describe a preset 3d shape (cube, circle, pyramid etc). 
I also have a 3d matrix stored in the nodes metadata that is used as an offset for the shape. This allows you to scale/move/rotate the shape without moving the transform.

The problem is in the way I am applying this matrix is very slow:

First I will create a new (edit)transform at the position of the (orig)transform containing the curves.
Next I will transfer cv positions in world space from (orig)transform to (edit)transform
Next i will move the  (edit)transform into the matrix position.
Finally I will transfer the cvPositions back to the (orig)transform

When creating hundreds of shapes, this is becoming prohibitively slow...

Can someone describe a mathematical way to apply a matrix to a set of 3d points?
Perhaps using one of the math modules or numpy?

Alternatively,

Is there a way using OpenMaya api functions to do this?  Perhaps with MPointArray?  This is as far as I have gotten on that front:

```
    crv = OpenMaya.MFnNurbsCurve( self.dagPath )
    cvs = OpenMaya.MPointArray()
    space = OpenMaya.MSpace.kWorld
    crv.getCVs(cvs, space)
    positions = []
    for i in range(cvs.length()):
        pt = cvs[i]
        positions.append( (pt[0], pt[1], pt[2]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use pymel's built-in versions of points and matrices (pymel is built in to maya 2011+). The math types are in pymel.datatatypes; here's an example of transforming  a point by a matrix in pymel:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pt = pm.datatypes.Point(0,0,0)
mt = pm.datatypes.Matrix(1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 5,5,5,1 )
moved = pt * mt
print moved
# [5,5,5]
```

Pymel points and matrices will let you do your algorithm. The math is going to be done in the API but the Python <> C++ conversions may still make it feel pretty slow for big data.

It sounds like you're basically re-creating 'freeze transforms' followed by 'zero pivots'.  Maybe you should try that as an alternative to doing this in python math...